# Get download link from Youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-chrome-devtools, youtube-javascript-api

When I enter the following in Chrome Developer Tools, Console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].src
```

I get:

```
"blob:https://www.youtube.com/7c1da720-75e6-49f4-86a9-a08d4a00c63b"
```

But I can't access this video with the http link above, how can I do it?

Comment: "Access" how specifically? Show the relevant code.

Comment: I do show the code in the question. The line produced should be the link to the video, but in Youtube it is not working, for other online platforms it works.